# Selenium taking too much time to download files

Tags: python, selenium

I am using this part of my code to download a some files which I download from clicking a link with a partial text specified, but even with my `driver.implicitly_wait(5)`, the driver is taking more then 2 minutes to check and download available files.

What's the best pythonic way to do the same as code below?

IMPORTANT, sometimes only one or two of the 4 files are available to download.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu"]/li[2]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="linkbtconsultar"]/a[1]/span').click()

try:
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('ASD!').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    return
try:
     driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('QWE#').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
     return
try:
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('RTY%').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    return
try:
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('ASD%').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    return
```

Comment: You want to improve your code performance or just the code quality ?

Comment: Both actually, is it suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would combine the 4 locators into one, return a collection of elements, and then loop through the collection clicking on each one.

Something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu"]/li[2]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="linkbtconsultar"]/a[1]/span').click()
docs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(.,'ASD!')] | //a[contains(.,'QWE#')] | //a[contains(.,'RTY%')] | //a[contains(.,'ASD%')]')
for doc in docs:
    doc.click()
    # you probably will need a brief wait here to give the browser time to process each click
```

This code will try to get all the desired docs and only return ones that exist... but it should be immediate.

Comment: Would this be better than a list of the elements? Or should this be a similar solution in speed matters?

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. `docs` is a collection (list) of elements that match all 4 of your posted locators. This should be much faster because it's only hitting the page once instead of 4 times and it shouldn't be waiting for elements that aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider not using Selenium to download the files and importing the requests module to do so. You could then use something like [map](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) to download all files at once.

```
try:
    files = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('file or extension')[:4]
except NoSuchElementException:
    return
for file in files:
    file.click()
```

Comment: The problem here is that i dont need do download all the files, but just the 1 to 4. The 5 and above i dont need

Comment: And i need selenium because there is a virtual keyboard to login and get to the download page, i think bs4 wont suit the clicking in the virtual keyboard i have mapped

Comment: Is there a way to use a dict with 1 2 3 and 4? I could scale this for other codes too.

Comment: open the network tab in your browser development tools and see if you can find out the download links....if you can you can download with requests module. BS doesnt make requests.

Comment: my answer now will only get links 1-4  that match the text

Comment: I see, i will try to check on the requests.

Comment: I added 1 to 4 as example, the files have specific and confidential names, thats why dict would be suitable